# How I get a bool value to check if there is a view to pop in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm junior developer in iOS.

I want to create a feature that the UIButton is not hidden when I get a View to can be Poped.

How I get some bool values from my NavigationViewController if they have previous view or not?

Thanks for read my question.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more clarification, or if my answer worked, can you click the green checkmark ✓ to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers) property:

```
if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers, viewControllers.count > 1 {
    /// has a previous view controller
}
```

But you're the one who's pushing and popping the view controllers... so you should be able to keep track by yourself.